# Unable to get kickstart file from http webserver?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, centos, httpd, kickstart

I'm trying to get a vm up using a kickstart file. However, whenever the virtual machine initalize, it says it is unable to located the kickstart file from the location provided.

Code to build vm:

```
virt-install --name guest --ram 2048 --disk /vm/guest.img --location /CentOS-6.6-x86_64-bin-DVD1.iso -x "ks=http://192.168.1.72/engineer.cfg ksdevice=eth0 ip=192.168.0.1 netmask=255.255.255.0 dns=8.8.8.8 gateway=192.168.1.254"
```

kickstarter file:

```
#platform=x86, AMD64, or Intel EM64T
#version=DEVEL
# Firewall configuration
firewall --disabled
# Install OS instead of upgrade
install
# Use network installation
url --url="http://192.168.1.72/"
# Root password
rootpw --iscrypted $1$AcXRM2i4$9Wzd1rjvrLNREmeIsM9.W1
# System authorization information
auth  --useshadow  --passalgo=sha512
# Use graphical install
graphical
firstboot --disable
# System keyboard
keyboard us
# System language
lang en_US
# SELinux configuration
selinux --enforcing
# Installation logging level
logging --level=info

# System timezone
timezone  Asia/Singapore
# Network information
network  --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0 --onboot=on
# System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr
# Clear the Master Boot Record
zerombr
# Partition clearing information
clearpart --all  
# Disk partitioning information
part /boot --fstype="ext4" --size=100
part swap --fstype="swap" --size=512
part / --fstype="ext4" --grow --size=1

%post
echo "ENGINEERING WORKSTATION" > /etc/issue
%end
```

The file is located at the /var/www/html directory of the webserver.

Any advice on what I may have missed will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your **.cfg** file have right permissions and is readable by other users/systems. You may try to wget or just simply open it from any other PC in your network and see if it works.

If you have permissions problem try to set chmod to 666.

```
chmod 666
```